# Quick escalation universe

Tags: riddle, video-games

```
This guy and his lot, always making things complicated.
Fortunately, I found that thing that makes rpg'ers feel heroic.
A distress, and its sibling bit
Time for Olympics! Go, go, go!
Let's admire the museum art.
Are you nuts?
Or religious?
It's hot in here.
Psychologist.
HA! Now YOU need a psychologist.
```

Edit 13 April 2019: I have been late, and I must add things:

Introspection
Adventures with psychic curvy curve

*And I'm not even mentioning the birds....*

Hint1:

> Flash

Hint2:

> Game's around for about 1 year

Hint3:

> By "quick escalation universe" I am expressing my view on the game's continuing episodes that they progressed rapidly

Hint4:

> Each line correspont to one episode

Super hint:

> He hates the post office.

Comment: Non-clue note: I removed a part which, after some thought, leads more to confusion.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this could be counted as a partial answer or just some random musings I've had, but this sounds like this riddle is

> Mario-related.

This guy and his lot, always making things complicated.

> Bowser and his minions are always out to cause trouble.

A distress, and its sibling bit

> Mario is often tasked with saving Princess Peach (a damsel in distress), and often enlists the help of his brother Luigi.

Time for Olympics! Go, go, go!

> There have been a series of Mario games which have been released to coincide with the Olympic and Winter Olympic games over the years.

Let's admire the museum art.

> In Super Mario 64, Mario enters a level by jumping into a painting.

Psychologist.

> There are Dr Mario games (tenuous link).

The sentence preceding the riddle:

In a multiverse where arguably people are falling into "oblivion"

> It could be argued that when Mario dies by falling he is falling into the unknown.

Comment: Mamma mia: Not the intended answer. However, one of your points is correct in essence.

Answer (score 2):

The Title "Quick Escalation Universe" strikes me as a cryptic reference to

> Accel World

And indeed there is a video game based on that series that was released approximately a year ago, namely:

> Accel World VS Sword Art Online: Millennium Twilight, released July 7, 2017

...but I don't know enough about the game or the series to know if it matches the other clues.

Comment: Wow, what things one learn! Not the intended answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about

> FORTNITE? (bear with me on these clues, I've never played the game)

This guy and his lot, always making things complicated.

> It's a complicated game?

Fortunately, I found that thing that makes rpg'ers feel heroic.

> Giant guns? Winning Battle Royales?

A distress, and its sibling bit

> There's apparently a distress signal/emergency signal?

Time for Olympics! Go, go, go!

> The [Fortnite Olympics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_pHFQOB3bs)?

Let's admire the museum art.

> There's now a [Musty Museum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_0QgDeC91Y)?

Are you nuts?

> People go crazy for the game

Or religious?

> Some people play it religiously (although I've seen religious articles decrying the game

It's hot in here.

> It's a hot new game

Psychologist. 
HA! Now YOU need a psychologist.

> Lots of psychologists have weighed in on the effects of Fortnite on children, especially with the violence.

As for the hints:

> [Flash](https://fortnite.gamepedia.com/Flash) 
>  The game's release date was July 25, 2017 
>  Fortnite is already on its 6th season, with new episodes, events, and locations being added all the time (even though it's only 1 year old).

Comment: Nope, it's not it

Answer (score 2):

I think it's

> Fallout 4

This guy and his lot, always making things complicated.

> Yeah,I play this game 3 hours a day but I can't complete it.

Fortunately, I found that thing that makes rpg'ers feel heroic.

> Lots of armor,weapon,enemies,missions...

A distress, and its sibling bit

> Your brother becomes the worst Raider and you have to kill it

Time for Olympics! Go, go, go!

> Says some man when he give you a mission to kill your bro

Let's admire the museum art.

> Raiders in the museum

Are you nuts?
Or religious?

> Lots of religions

It's hot in here.

> Sun is hotter than ever because of rad

Psychologist.
HA! Now YOU need a psychologist.

> That's what your brother says when you start killing him

Comment: Nope, much older than a year

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is talking about

> Super Smash Brothers.

Each line either describes a stage or character in said game, although...

...This will be a partial answer, since I'm still working out what each line means, as I'm not sure this is the answer. At least, this is what I have for now:

This guy and his lot, always making things complicated.

> Now this could be talking about basically any villain in the game, but I'm gonna go with Bowser as he comes with Bowser Jr. and the koopa kids as "his lot"

Fortunately, I found that thing that makes rpg'ers feel heroic

> This I imagine has something to do with Cloud Strife being in the game, although it could also be related to Shulk (being from an RPG and having "heroic" themes)

A distress, and its sibling bit

> A distress could be talking about Peach, and sibling is most likely Luigi.

It's hot in here.

> The Metroid stage Midfair takes place inside a volcano (pretty hot!)

In a multiverse where arguably people are falling into "oblivion"

> This is probably the strongest tie to SSB, as it is a multiverse of several Nintendo (and third party) franchises. In addition, falling into "oblivion" is the core way of winning the game - knocking your opponents off the screen.

Comment: This...is impressive. Still, not the intended answer.

Comment: Falling into oblivion, could also mean being sucked into Kirby's pocket dimension :)